# Jmeter not running for particular scenario

Tags: jmeter

I am not able to run `jmeter` on this particular url- https://www.yatra.com/

It is working on other website like- https://www.makemytrip.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different sites have different policies of how it can be accessed, that is why you can not do it.

You should practice Jmeter either on the application you are working on or else you can refer the below answer:
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/23828/applications-for-practicing-performance-testing-from-home